# How to describe the bass tone/timbre heard in the examples?

Tags: bass, timbre

I've been looking around for good sounding bass tones for quite a while. The only problem is that when I do find something, I don't know how to describe it.

So here's what I've found. The style could be considered electronic. I'm looking for "names" or descriptions of the bass tones in the following songs. And I know that most of this is probably accomplished with a keyboard and a DAW but, it would be helpful to know if there are any pedals that can do "electronic" bass.

It starts on measure 8, beat 3<sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub> (<sup>4</sup>⁄<sub>4</sub> time). It sounds like a clean bass sound with an added punch and high tones.

Starts on measure 5 (<sup>4</sup>⁄<sub>4</sub> also). Here it sounds similar to the last song, but with higher tones and some kind of reverb, I guess.

Comment: To bad I'm not working festivals any more or I'd ask Toby the next time I saw him.

Comment: @AJHenderson Wow! You know him?

Comment: Don't know him, but I used to be back stage with him from time to time.  Most of the Christian music scene, with only a few exceptions, is very approachable as long as they aren't in performance mode and you treat them like a normal human being.  I used to work as a video guy with a regional festival in the US North East but haven't had the time to take off from my day job the last 5 or so years to go out to it.  It's funny because you actually learn to recognize the look in their eyes and the visible relaxing when they are trying to figure out if you are an obsessed fan or going to be normal.

Comment: @AJHenderson That's really interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first one I think it is actually a combination of two sounds.  I think it may be a clean bass with the synthesized higher/mid sound being imposed over top of it.  The same electronic instrument seems to be used in higher octaves later in the first song.  There is also some volume pulsing with the beat to give it that added punch I think you are talking about.

The volume pulsing is much more pronounced in the TobyMac song and was actually a technique he liked a lot in that album and has used in a few other of his albums.  In that song I'm pretty sure it is purely a synthesised sound though.  It's possible that it is fully synthesised in both songs though, Owl City and TobyMac are both very electronic in style.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks man. I started a bounty to see if I can get any more answers.